How do I find $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{2}{3}} \left( (x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)$?
I'm currently trying to find $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{2}{3}} \left( (x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)$$
I have tried multiplying the numerator and denominator by $$ (x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} + x^{\frac{2}{3}}$$
but then I don't know how to proceed if this is a correct method to utilize.

Hint: Apply the mean value theorem.

Hint: $A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$

Prove: $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{2/3}((x+1)^{1/3}-x^{1/3})=1/3$ is a duplicate.

I didn't know this before I started my answer. I can delete my answer.

$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{2}{3}} \left( (x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}} \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Apply L'Hôpital's rule:
$$ L = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{3\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^{\frac{2} {3}}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\frac{2}{3}} \left( (x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^2(x+1))^{\frac{1}{3}}-x}{1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac1x)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{\frac1x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac13(1+\frac1x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\text{   (L'Hôpital's)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac13(1+\frac1x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(-\frac{1}{x^2})}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac13\frac{1}{(1+\frac1x)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\\
&=\frac13.
\end{align}
I see there is no difference from answer by Bertrand87.
However, there is other possible solution approach. For instance, it can be not so tedious to use generalized Binomial coefficient.
\begin{align}
\left(1+x\right)^{\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{\alpha}\choose{k}}\cdot x^k
=1+{\alpha}x+\frac{\alpha\left(\alpha-1\right)}{2}x^2+\ldots
\end{align}
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac1x)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{\frac1x}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1+\frac13t-\frac19t+\frac{5}{81}t^2+\ldots\mathbf{-1}}{t}\\
&=\frac13.
\end{align}
